# How to switch tabs in Safari with mouse gesture?

Tags: safari

In Safari, how to switch tabs using mouse gesture? I try to use the BetterTouchTool, since there's no shortcut to switch tabs, I have no idea how to config in BetterTouchTool too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have BetterTouchTool, this is pretty easy. Simply choose whatever gestures you want to use for tab-switching and assign them the following keyboard shortcuts:

[image][image]

These shortcuts are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> respectively. The first shortcut will switch to the next tab, and the latter will switch to the previous tab.

Comment: I don't think that BetterTouchTool has an option for switching between tabs, but they have a lot of other options. I've yet to find a way to switch between tabs using only the trackpad.